# Get to the space character in level 9

Tags: vim-adventures

How do I (using vi commands) get to a space character that is not on the same line as I am on? I need to get to the space character that is marked by the red "2" in one key sequence.

[image]

Comment: Never played vim-adventures, but it appears that '4j' will get you from the 'n' to the space 4 characters below.

Comment: ken.ganong had an awesome suggestion. `4j` will move you down 4 times. You can then use `0` to go to the beginning of the line. From there it's pretty much the same thing. I'm stuck on square 5 trying to get to 6 though... If you got though this and managed to land on square 6 I'd love to know how...

Comment: I just figured it out. One thing that stumped me for the longest time is that you can use the numbers along with the `$` command. I hope that helps anyone else looking at this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Step 0: First you need to remember the search for [space], this will save on one     keystroke later on

  > f[space]
- Step 1: To start over with the search remembered

  > kj
- Step 2: to move down 4 times

  > 4j
- Step 3: to go to the beginning of the line

  > 0
- Step 4: to move up 2 times

  > 2k
- Step 5: to move 3 words forward

  > 3w
- Step 6: to the very end

  > 99e
- Step 7: to search for  backwards remembered at step 0

  > ,

Comment: How do you get back to the `n` in `don't` once the key appears?

Comment: For instance:
8b f[space] 5k

Comment: @IlyaKharlamov I'm stuck here too but every time I try to use a number (eg 4j) I get "I don't have the 4 button". How did you activate number prefixes?

Comment: @Julian You've got to find it. It's somewhere around (In the hous e or in the bushes, don't remember exacly).

Comment: @IlyaKharlamov thanks! Found it solving the puzzle to the top right of this one!

Comment: User "Caio Abe" says: "instead of `99e` you could use `4$` as an alternative too"

Comment: An alternative step 9 is using `n` if like me vim adventures remembers the full stop work `.` when I used `*` or `#` (forget which) in the previous puzzle.

Comment: @LukeImhoff what worked for me (to get back to `n`/beginning of the puzzle to get the key) was doing `5G` to get to the line with `h`. Then `4l` then `4k`. the key was realizing `G` with a count prefix gets you to a specific line! :)